# Pass JSON response outside of the function

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4

How can I pass my JSON response (`data`) from the `getStories()` function to a new variable (`var stories`) which is outside of my function and after that to be able to use that new variable into my CollectionViewController ?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class StoryCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    // MARK: - ***** Properties *****
    private var stories: Story!

    // MARK: - ***** Life Cycles *****
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell class
        collectionView?.register(UINib.init(nibName: "StoryCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Constants.reuseIdentifier)

        // Get Stories
        getStories()

        print(stories.storyID) // Here should return 15 but return NIL and I don't know why
    }

    // MARK: ***** UICollectionView DataSource Methods *****
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! StoryCollectionViewCell

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //cell.storyImageView.imageFromServerURL(urlString: self.posterUrl)
            //cell.storyNameLabel.text = self.stories?.name
        }

        return cell
    }

    //MARK: - ***** CollectionView Delegate Methods *****
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showStoryDetails", sender: self.stories)
    }

    // Get Stories from Amazon API server
    func getStories(){

        Spinner.show("Loading Stories")

        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        if let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: Constants.baseURL) {

            guard let url = urlComponents.url else { return }

            let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in

                if error != nil {

                    self.showMessage(message: error.debugDescription)
                } else if let data = data {

                    do {
                        let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(ModelJson.self, from: data)

                        self.stories = data.result // This object "stories" is empty outside of this function ..........

                        print("Story ID: \(self.stories.storyID!)") // Here return 15 which is correct
                    } catch {
                        self.showMessage(message: error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
                Spinner.hide()
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screen to show you that my JSON response contains data and return 15 in console:
[image: JSON response contains data]

Thank you guys if you are reading this.
Have a great day !

Comment: The code works fine and **asynchronously**. Delete the `print` line in `viewDidLoad` and do the things you want to do in the completion handler after or instead of the *working* `print` line. And don't forget to reload the collection view on the main thread. And why is the collection view optional?

Comment: Modify the function to take a completion handler: `func getStories(completion: (Story) -> Void)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use closure in getStories function like this:

```
func getStories(CompletionHandler: @escaping (Story)->()) {
     // 
}
```

and after data get called, call this closure like this:

```
CompletionHandler(data.result)
```

Then, when calling this method, you can handle your object inside the closure and update your controller as you need.

```
getStories { [weak self] (stories) in
    self?.stories = stories
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getStories` method contains. asynchronous operation. It means that you get response not immediately. You can't get stories after calling the `getStories` method. Do it after you set stories property. Example:

```
func getStories(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    Spinner.show("Loading Stories")

    let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    if let urlComponents = URLComponents(string: Constants.baseURL) {
        guard let url = urlComponents.url else { return }

        let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
            if error != nil {

                self.showMessage(message: error.debugDescription)
            } else if let data = data {
                do {
                    let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(ModelJson.self, from: data)

                    self.stories = data.result
                } catch {
                    self.showMessage(message: error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            Spinner.hide()
            completion()
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getStories(completion: { [weak self] in
        self?.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```